# Angular5 highcharts custom buttons won't work

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular5

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular to produce highcharts in Angular.

The custom exporting buttons do no show up on the graph. When I was using angular4, with https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts, the custom buttons were showing. However, I needed to change my library to the official one. Has anyone else had this issue?

```
        this._chartOptions_Graph_Default = {
        title: { 
            text: 'title'
            useHTML : true,
        },
        series: seriesWrapper[0],
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            visible: true,
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false // hover
                    },
                },
                animation: false,
                gapSize: 2,
            },
            turboThreshold : 0,

        },
        tooltip: { enabled: true },
        exporting :{
            buttons:{
                customButton: {
                    text: 'Custom Button',
                    onclick: function () {
                        alert('You pressed the button!');
                    }
                }
            }

        },
        chart: {
            zoomType : 'x'
          },

    }
```

Comment: Have you added the exporting module? Works fine on pure JS with exporting module added: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1hx4sh1r/ More about adding a module to the `highcharts-angular`: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module